# Is Oracle ADF Essential and OEPE Eclipse is discouraged by Oracle?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, oracle-adf

Based on search in internet web sites, Whenever I tried to find a sample or advanced Task Flow based ADF Application created purely using [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html) and Glassfish I only end up with a blog entry 5 year old.

When I try to read any ebook, I end up with JDeveloper and weblogic.

When I try to read the tutorial videos from the official oracle website and oracle official YouTube channels I end up with JDeveloper and weblogic.

Does this means that there will be no support provided by oracle for OEPE and ADF Essentials?

Also the basic tutorial for OEPE is too old. Few basic Unbounded Task flow techniques are not working with OEPE and ADF Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the state of things is exactly as you described.

It looks like there's some sort of development occasionally going on the OEPE repository with the last change being made on 2016-12-19.

I think that some level of support will probably be provided, and frankly it's pretty much the same level of support that has been available for years - low.

Anyone that needs to make a choice (or has a choice for that matter) should take a long, hard look at the situation as it is.